# In HighchartJS doing the legent in multiple and adding extra legents

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to HighChart, I want to make the following style of dataset.

[image]

Is there any way to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can you will need to customize  legend using various attributes provided by highcharts. It also provides feature to use custom HTML to design a legend. below is sample legend property that you can use to define the position, alignment and html formatting etc.

```
legend: {
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      layout: 'vertical',
      x: -50,
      y: 120,
      symbolPadding: 0,
      symbolWidth: 0.1,
      symbolHeight: 0.1,
      symbolRadius: 0,
      useHTML: true,  
      labelFormatter: function() {

        return '<div style="width:200px;"></span><span style="float:right;padding:9px">' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + " " + this.y + '%</span></div>';
      },
},
```